# circular imports vs parent/child design

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am relatively new to Python and struggling with circular imports with the design I am going for.

Here is a very simplified design I am going for:

main.py, model.py, encounter.py and unit.py

Model is the root node that contains a bunch of lists of children objects but each child has a reference to Model to allow it access to all the information. Below is not 100% good code but I hope shows what I am trying to do.

model.py looks something like this:

```
from encounter import Encounter
from unit import Unit
@dataclass
class Model:
     encounters: [Encounter] 
     units: [Unit]
```

encounter.py would look something like this:

```
from model import Model
@dataclass
class Encounter:
    model: Model
    identifier: str
    name: str
    def some_method(self):
        for (unit in self.model.units):
            #do something
```

unit.py would similar

```
from model import Model
@dataclass
class Unit:
    model: Model
    identifier: str
    name: str
    def some_method(self):
        for (enc in self.model.encounters):
            #do something
```

in main.py, I would construct a new Model and then start adding encounters and units. throughput my program, would then call unit.some_method or enc.some_method.

```
from model import Model
from encounter import Encounter
from unit import Unit

model = Model(start_date_time=start_date, finish_date_time=finish_date)
model.encounters.append(Encounter(model, "id1", "name1")
model.encounters.append(Encounter(model, "id2", "name2")
model.encounters.append(Encounter(model, "id3", "name3")

model.units.append(Unit(model, "id1", "name1")
model.units.append(Unit(model, "id2", "name2")
model.units.append(Unit(model, "id3", "name3")

model.encounters[0].some_method()
```

When I try for this design, I get essentially this error in vs code:

"cannot import name 'Encounter' from partially initialized module 'encounter' (most likely due to a circular import) "

the only fix is to remove the "from model import Model". That works but, now I lose the IntelliSense in VS Code which is not the end of the world but my gut says there is a way I can have my cake and eat it too here.

Any thoughts on how to pull of these type of design?

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For typehints, the typing module provides the [`typing.TYPE_CHECKING`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TYPE_CHECKING) constant with which can be used as a guard on the imports which cause a cycle, and are only used in annotations.

You can use the above style combined with a forward reference `name: "type"` on the type hint which will prevent it from being evaluated as an expression, or a `from __future__ import annotations` import which does this implicitly for all annotations. This will prevent the imports from actually executing at runtime, but still be valid to a type checker

As an example if two files depend on each other only through the type hints, it would look something like this

```py
# a.py
if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:
    from b import B

class A:
    b_obj: "B"
```

```py
# b.py
if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:
    from a import A

class B:
    a_obj: "A"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `model.py` to

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List

@dataclass
class Model:
    encounters: List['Encounter']
    units: List['Unit']


from encounter import Encounter
from unit import Unit
```

By moving the imports from `encounter` and `unit` to the end, the class `Model` is defined when those modules import from `model`. But then we need to name the types `Encounter` and `Unit` by strings inside `Model`.